# Laravel: Difference between $request->all() and $request->input()

Tags: laravel

What is the difference between `$request->all()` and `$request->input()`?

According to their documentation, they look very similar to each other:

> You may retrieve all of the incoming request's input data as an array using the `all` method.

> You may call the `input` method without any arguments in order to retrieve all of the input values as an associative array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input()` gets all input values and query string parameters.

`all()` is like `input()` but also includes all files.

Comment: `$request->all()` is what you need when you want to validate form file input. Use `$request->input()` if you just need to validate text input.

Answer (score 1):

```
$request->all()
```

usage comes if you wish to fetch all data passed as a collection.
Below is an example that gets all data and creates a record in your database table as per model usage.

```
public function post(Request $request)
  {
        $post = new Status();
        $post->create($request->all());
  }
```

```
$request->input()
```

Usage comes if you wish to fetch a variable passed as a single parameter.
Below is an example that gets data and creates a record in your database table as per model usage.

```
public function post(Request $request)
  {

//get data as parameters passed from your form

    $title   = $request->input('title');
    $author  = $request->input('author');

//you can save data like this....This is just an example
 DB::table('posts')
     ->insert([
     'title'   => $title,
     'author'  => $author,
     'created_at'    => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
     'updated_at'    => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
     ]);           
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @ParisaN for improving on my answer.

Comment: The OP was actually asking for clarification when using the `input` method without any parameters as this behaves *exactly* like calling the `all` method.